# how to display json date in timestamp format in html

Tags: javascript

I need to convert json date time to string and write it html table cell. Json I am getting is like this:

```
 "creation": {
        "date": {
            "year": 2022,
            "month": 1,
            "day": 9
        },
        "time": {
            "hour": 10,
            "minute": 14,
            "second": 11,
            "nano": 830000000
        }
```

I want to display it like this : 1-9-2022 10:14:11:83000000
Is there built-in function in JS. Your help appreciated

Comment: you can use [Javascript Date() object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own function using template literals, check the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
const creation = {
  date: {
      year: 2022,
      month: 1,
      day: 9
  },
  time: {
      hour: 10,
      minute: 14,
      second: 11,
      nano: 830000000
  }
}

const renderTimestanp = ({date, time}) => `${date.month}-${date.day}-${date.year} ${time.hour}:${time.minute}:${time.second}:${time.nano}`

// will return 1-9-2022 10:14:11:83000000
renderTimestanp(creation)
```

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build in function, but simple string concatenation will work:

```js
var time = {
  "creation": {
    "date": {
      "year": 2022,
      "month": 1,
      "day": 9
    },
    "time": {
      "hour": 10,
      "minute": 14,
      "second": 11,
      "nano": 830000000
    }
  }
};

console.log(
  '' + time.creation.date.month + '-' + time.creation.date.day + '-' + time.creation.date.year +
  ' ' +
  time.creation.time.hour + ':' + time.creation.time.minute + ':' + time.creation.time.second + ':' + time.creation.time.nano
);
```

Comment: For this case, it's better to use template literals

Comment: @Maxime How it's better? Only for readability, but serves same purpose

Comment: yes for readability

Comment: readability, understanding, learning... if all we do here in StackOverflow is to help, why not do it in the best way possible? 
I'm almost sure if you code-review someone that have written your code, you would ask to improve it 

Comment: agree. Maxime solution is reusable and I can call it in places like creation and resolution. Thanks you all